# ssh tunnel for postgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, ssh, tunnel

I have two servers. For example1.com and example2.com

At example1.com server I have my php code and example2.com there is a postgreSQL database.

Now I want to connect postgreSQL through a tunnel in example1.com

I tried the following command at example1.com server.

```
ssh -L 5433:localhost:5432 user@example2.com
```

Then it will prompt for password and I enter the password and login to ssh, then I am trying to connect to database localhost:5433 post but I am getting 'password authentication failed'.

How do I connect to example1.com through ssh?

Comment: it seems there is issue with postgresql configuration setting. check listen_addresses setting in postgresql config file

Comment: Are you trying to connect to the database localhost:5433 on the SSH session to example2.com, or from your example1.com server? Are you connecting from PHP or from psql?

Comment: i am trying to connect to database through localhost:5433 through php.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the `pg_hba.conf` on your PostgreSQL server.  It probably requires password authentication for TCP/IP connections coming from localhost.  So you either need to change that, or set a password for your database user and enter that.